# What is the difference between creating a new Map with or without parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I'm able to create a new Map without the parentheses like so

`const withoutParentheses = new Map;`

or like this

`const withParentheses = new Map();`

Same goes for `Set`

I haven't been able to find any differences between the two, but are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check here for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/can-we-omit-parentheses-when-creating-an-object-using-the-new-operator). In short,
If you do not have arguments to pass, the parentheses are optional.